# My Gatsby/Drupal site fails during build because of one content in Drupal. How do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drupal, graphql, gatsby

I have a Gatsby site that connects to Drupal CMS via GraphQL to get the content from there. It has separate dynamic pages for each of the content items.

I works fine when I type `gatsby develop` in the terminal and run the site locally.

However, when I try to build it using the command `gatsby build`, the build process fails and apparently it is due to one of the content items that is extracted from the Drupal CMS.

I tried to use the link provided in the error message and I got this:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {processed}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Below is the error message:

```
 ERROR 

Page data from page-data.json for the failed page "/staff/v-coleman": {
  "componentChunkName": "component---src-dynamic-doctor-profile-js",
  "path": "/staff/v-coleman",
  "result": {
    "data": {
      "nodeAccountant": {
        "id": "77",
        "name": "V. Coleman",
        "designation": "Chief Accountant",
        "expertise": "\"Payables \r\nIMRT\r\n4D gated RT\r\n3DCRT\r\nReceivables\r\Text: More and more text...",
        "availability": null,
        "experience": null,
        "Education": {
          "processed": "<ul>\n\t<li>College Name, Country: Year</li>\n\t<li>College at Country : Year</li>\n\t<li>Certification Name
 under Mentor Name at Country Name in Year</li>\n</ul>"
        },
        "training": null,
        "affiliations": {
          "processed": "<ul>\n\t<li>ABC - Uganda</li>\n\t<li>ZYX – Germany</li>\n\t<li>QWERTY - Italy</li>\n</ul>"
        },
        "books": {
          "processed": "<h4><strong>Basic Accounting</strong></h4>\n\n<ul>\n\t<li>Details...</li>\n\t<li>More text</li>\n</ul>\n\n<h4><strong>More text</st..."
        },
        "recognition": {
          "processed": "<ul>\n\t<li>Lots of text..."
        },
        "phd": null,
        "volunteer_work": null
      },
      "allNodeAccountant": {
        "nodes": [
          {
            "id": "0",
            "name": "Name 1",
            "designation": "Designation 1",
            "experience": null
          },
          {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Name 2",
            "designation": "Designation 2",
            "experience": null
          },
          {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Name 3",
            "designation": "Designation 3",
            "experience": null
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "pageContext": {
      "doctorID": "77"
    }
  },
  "staticQueryHashes": []
}

failed Building static HTML for pages - 8.564s

 ERROR #95313 

Building static HTML failed for path "/staff/v-coleman"

See our docs page for more info on this error: https://gatsby.dev/debug-html


  2 |
  3 | function _inheritsLoose(subClass, superClass) {
> 4 |   subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass.prototype);
    | ^
  5 |   subClass.prototype.constructor = subClass;
  6 |   setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass);
  7 | }


  WebpackError: Minified React error #31; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=31&args[]=object%20with%20keys%20%7Bprocessed%7D for the full messa
  ge or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
  
  - inheritsLoose.js:4 
    [gatsby-starter-hello-world]/[@babel]/runtime/helpers/inheritsLoose.js:4:1
  
  - inheritsLoose.js:7 
    [gatsby-starter-hello-world]/[@babel]/runtime/helpers/inheritsLoose.js:7:1
  
  - static-entry.js:294 
    gatsby-starter-hello-world/.cache/static-entry.js:294:22
  
  - utils.js:51 
    [gatsby-starter-hello-world]/[@gatsbyjs]/reach-router/lib/utils.js:51:1
```

And below is the template for the dynamic pages:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { Link } from "gatsby";
import Layout from '../components/Layout';
import { graphql } from "gatsby";

const accountantProfile = ({ data }) => {
    const accountant = data.nodeAccountant;
    const accountants = data.allNodeAccountant.nodes;

    return (<Fragment>
        <Layout>
            <main>
                <section>
                    <h2>{accountant.designation}</h2>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <h3>{accountant.name}</h3>
                                <h4>{accountant.designation}</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <h5>
                                    <img loading='lazy' src="/icons/expertise.svg" alt="" />
                                    Areas of Expertise</h5>
                                <p>{accountant.expertise}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <picture class="hero_image text-center">
                                <source media="(min-width:1024px)"
                                    srcset="/dr_profile.png" />
                                <source media="(min-width:300px)"
                                    srcset="/dr_profile.png" />
                                <img loading='lazy' src="/dr_profile.png" alt="" />
                            </picture>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <div id="accordion">
                                    <div class="card">
                                        <div id="headingTwo">
                                            <h5 class="mb-0">
                                                <a href="#aboutAccountant">
                                                    About the Accountant
                                                </a>
                                            </h5>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="aboutAccountant">
                                            <div>{'' + accountant.name + ' is a ' + accountant.designation + '.'}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    {accountant.books &&
                                        <div>
                                            <div id="heading10">
                                                <h5>
                                                    <a href="#Publications">
                                                        Publications
                                                    </a>
                                                </h5>
                                            </div>
                                            <div id="Publications">
                                                <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: accountant.books.processed }} />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    }
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {/* consulants */}
                            <div>
                                <div>
                                    <h2>Accountants</h2>
                                    {accountants.map((acc, i = 0) => {
                                        if (i < 4) {
                                            return (<div>
                                                <figure>
                                                    <img loading='lazy' src="/accountant_img.png" alt="" />
                                                </figure>
                                                <div>
                                                    <h3>{acc.name}
                                                        <br />
                                                        <span>{acc.designation}</span>
                                                    </h3>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>);
                                        }
                                        i++;
                                    })
                                    }
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </main>
        </Layout>

    </Fragment>);
};

export default accountantProfile;

export const query = graphql`
  query($accountantID: String!) {
    nodeAccountant(id: {eq: $accountantID}) {
        id
        name
        designation
        expertise
        availability
        experience
        Education {
            processed
        }
        training {
            processed
        }
        affiliations {
            processed
        }
        books {
            processed
        }
        recognition {
            processed
        }
        phd {
            processed
        }
        volunteer_work {
            processed
        }
        books {
            processed
        }
    }
    allNodeAccountant {
        nodes {
            id
            name
            designation
            experience
        }
    }
  }
`;
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you share the offending page/template? (`/staff/v-coleman`)

Comment: @FerranBuireu I just shared it.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue raises because you have two repeated keys in your GraphQL query. You have two times the following:

```
    books {
        processed
    }
```

Getting rid of one of them should fix your issue.

Obviously the offending line is:

```
<div id="Publications">
   <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: accountant.books.processed }} /> 
</div>
```

Try using a HTML parser ([`html-react-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser)):

```
import parse from 'html-react-parser';

{parse(accountant.books.processed)}
```

Comment: I tried it but still got the same error message

Comment: If you remove the `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: accountant.books.processed }} />` (just to try) , is the error gone?

Comment: I removed it and now the error message is gone. However, I need that line of code.

Comment: I changed the alias for processed but still got the same problem

Comment: Have you tried using an HTML parser? Could be that books are an array and you may need to do: `accountant.books[0].processed`. Can you log your `accountant` data?

Comment: actually books is an html string not an array. I don't want to log the accountant data cause I modified it before posting the question. Can I send it to you privately instead?

Comment: I was having some trouble loging into the chat feature so I messaged you on Twitter.